# How does WCF serialize the method call?

Tags: wcf, serialization

I am wondering how WCF serialize the method call,  e.g. how the target class, method, method parameters are serialized,  anybody has idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is fundamentally a SOAP message service - so your messages will be SOAP messages, with all the SOAP envelopes, containing headers and body.

Check out the great [Service Station: Serialization In WCF](https://web.archive.org/web/20140519204507/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx) MSDN article by Aaron Skonnard for an extensive discussion of all the ins and outs of serializing messages in WCF. Highly recommended reading.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to find out! If you set up a WCF service using HTTP bindings, Fiddler can show you the traffic between your client and service.

Comment: it must be something like SOAP, i think.

Comment: @Benny: it **IS** SOAP - all the way (unless you use WebHttpBinding, then it's REST)

Answer (score 1):

MSDN:

- [WCF Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx),
- [Data Transfer and Serialization in Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730035.aspx).