# How to wrap all results of an EndPoint in OperationResult?

Tags: wcf

I want to wrap each result from one Wcf service in my application in something like

```
public class OperationResult{
  public string Status;
  public string Data;
}
```

even if my contract looks like

```
[ServiceContract]
internal interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract,
     WebGet(
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    MyDc EchoDc(MyDc input);
}
```

From what I've read the potential extensibility points are IServiceBehavior, IEndpointBehavior, IContractBehavior, IOperationBehavior.

Any thoughts where I can hook my wrapping magic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look @ my answer here:

[How to customize the process employed by WCF when serializing contract method arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030969/how-to-customize-the-process-employed-by-wcf-when-serializing-contract-method-arg/3100277#3100277)

There it is mentioned how you can replace an object of one type to another type while it is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats not possible via extensionpoints on the WCF framework because what you watn to do is to change your contract.

The contract is a c# interface which is used by your client.

You have to write an own proxy class for use by your client where you can map the operation results to whatever you like:

```
class ServiceProxy : ClientBase<YourServiceInterface>
{

    public OperationResult EchoDc(MyDs input)
    {
        MyDc result = Channel.EchoDc(input);
        return new OperationResult( ... // map your operation result here))
    }
}
```

Comment: The clients are not necessary .Net consumers ... and they expect the result to be a json object like {Status:200, Data:{Age:20, Name:"Yogy"}}

Comment: Ok, but the contract specifies your return datatype. You can't change that without changing your contract.

Comment: but in a REST context, the contract doesn't matter much. Still, I don't get why he doesn't either change his contract, or else return status out-of-band.